# readFileSync - no such file or directory on packaged app

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js, electron, fs

I am working on an Electron app.
I have several JSON files from my src folder that need to be copied over to a user-folder during app initialization (settings, config, etc).

It works well when on dev mode and when I do `import` the JSON files.

But based on how I need it, `readFileSync` is the best way to implement this.

```
var srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../config/settings.json')
fs.readFileSync(srcPath)
```

I am getting an error though when running the packaged exe app (in asar). 
Getting error messages like this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodeJS\branches\Electron
\myApp\dist\electron\My-App-win32-x64\resources\config\settings.json'
```

`readdirSync()` also does not work for the same reason.

I understand that my relative path is different in the packaged version
I checked the asar file and I can't seem to find my JSON files. Not sure if I am checking correctly though since it is bundled up by Webpack.

My file in this example is located in:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodeJS\branches\Electron\myApp\src\config\settings.json
```

How can I make this work?

Is there a way to force electron (I am using Electron-Packager with Quasar framework) to include my JSON files in the packaged app?

Does Webpack not bundle up the JSON files??

Thoughts? Help please!

Comment: I need to read from my srcPath (dev directory).. But since I am using ```__dir```, path becomes different when I am running using the packaged app (.exe in the dist folder). Can't really do an absolute path since it will mess up other developers codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I just created a folder that will contain 'post-packaging' scripts. One of which does a copy from my src folder to my dist\electron\appName\resources folder (using `robocopy`).